# Concatenating multiple line variables using newline

Tags: bash, concatenation

I have two variables `var1` and `var2` that could either be multiple lines or could be completely empty. For example, either one could look like:

```
line/1
line/2
```

or

I want to concatenate them so that when put together var1 outputs as is, and var 2 outputs as is right below the last line of var1. There are 4 cases, either var1 is empty and var2 is not, var 2 is empty and var 1 is not, both are empty, or neither are empty. I dont want any whitespace or an empty line if one of the variables is empty. So if var 1 is empty I do not want,

```
line/1
```

or vice versa.

Other than using a if, elif, else block, is there a way I could do this or do I HAVE to use an if else block.

In addition, for the last case where neither are empty how can I concatenate these two? I have tried

```
var3="${var1}\n${var2}"
```

but that doesn't seem to work. Any tips would be much appreciated.

Comment: `\n` does not interpolate a newline character, but a literal `\` followed by a `n`. You can verify this by doing a, say, `xxd <<<$var3`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `bash`, you can use this function for this job:

```
concat() {
   printf '%s' "${1:+$1$'\n'}" "${2:+$2$'\n'}";
}
```

Use of `"${1:+$1$'\n'}"` appends `\n` to `$1` only if `$1` is null/unset.

As per `man bash`:

`${parameter:+word}`
              Use Alternate Value.  If parameter is null or unset, nothing is substituted, otherwise the expansion of word is substituted.

**Examples:**

```
concat 'line1' 'line2'
```

```
line1
line2
```

```
concat 'line1' ''
```

```
line1
```

```
concat '' 'line2'
```

```
line2
```

```
concat '' ''
```

```
concat 'line1
line2
line3' ''
```

```
line1
line2
line3
```

Comment: thank you, this actually worked perfectly. The explanation was very insightful as well!

Answer (score 2):

```
var3="$var1${var1:+${var2:+$'\n'}}$var2"
```

should work.

```
$ var1=; var2=; var3="${var1}${var1:+${var2:+$'\n'}}${var2}"; echo "$var3"
               # empty line from echo
$ var1=1; var2=; var3="${var1}${var1:+${var2:+$'\n'}}${var2}"; echo "$var3"
1
$ var1=; var2=2; var3="${var1}${var1:+${var2:+$'\n'}}${var2}"; echo "$var3"
2
$ var1=1; var2=2; var3="${var1}${var1:+${var2:+$'\n'}}${var2}"; echo "$var3"
1
2
```

- `${var1}` - put var1
- `${var1:+` - when `var1` is set and

  - `${var2:+` - when `var2` is set

    - `$'\n'` - then add a newline
  - `}`
- `}`
- `${var2}` - and add var2 too.

Basically the `${var1:+${var2:+$'\n'}}` adds a newline only if `var1` and `var2` are both set, to separate `var1` and `var2`.

For reference [bash manual shell parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html).

Comment: It's literally explained below. Maybe refresh the page, I edited the post.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using `printf -v`

```
printf -v var3 '%s\n "$var1" "$var2"
```

Comment: what exactly does the -v modifier do? What does the %s\n do?

Comment: Still, when `var1` or `var2` are empty, this will result in empty lines.

Comment: @KamilCuk indeed

Comment: @nutella100 `help prinf`  `-v var    assign the output to shell variable VAR rather than
display it on the standard output`